# error in azure portal when trying to view all registered stored procedures in documentdb: Failed to get scripts

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I created a couple of API methods [based on this explanation](https://russellyoung.net/2016/06/18/managing-documentdb-with-powershell/) to create stored procedures with Powershell for documentdb.

When trying to check if the stored procedures are indeed in the portal available, I receive an error that says:

```
Failed to get scripts. Please try again.
```

I can retrieve the registered stored procedures with another API call from powershell, and I can also delete the stored procedures without any error message. When I deleted all the scripts, the error message disappears too. So the Portal does recognize that I registered stored procedures, but it seems it just fails to visualize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to get scripts. Please try again.

I could reproduce the issue on my side, if the body of the stored procedure contains **\r\n** and write it in multi lines.

```
$requestbody = '{"id":"TestSprocf","body":"function (name){\r\n
var response = getContext().getResponse();
\r\nresponse.setBody(name);
\r\n}"}' 

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers $hdrs -Body $requestbody
```

Click **Refresh** button in Script Explorer, notification with failed error message will appear.

[image]

Please check the body of your stored procedure to make sure it is written in above format.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! After a little testing, it seems that it fails to read the stored procedure if a space comes directly after the r\n\ . Just don't put a space or tab behind \r\n and the error should not occur. It should be noted that the example on the  [microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/create-a-stored-procedure) is a little bit confusig, since they manage to get the body of the request work with tabs included.